# Ionic serve doesn't work

Tags: ionic-framework

First time i use Ionic.
I'm trying to run an existing project with : `ionic serve` :

```
watch started ... 
build dev started ... 
Proxy added:/api => http://[...]
clean started ... 
clean finished in 9 ms 
copy started ... 
transpile started ... 
transpile finished in 2.31 s 
preprocess started ... 
deeplinks started ... 
deeplinks finished in 82 ms 
preprocess finished in 84 ms 
webpack started ... 
copy finished in 2.50 s
```

but the server does not launch. I have no idea where the problem may come from.

Comment: You might want to show more than this, we can't see what is going on from this log. What command do you run, show some relevant code for example?

Comment: run both of these command and update question with both please. `ionic info` & `ionic serve -l -s -c`

Answer (score 1):

Assume you use Ionic 3.6.0.

Usually, you get that type of error because you put two or more classes into one .ts file.

Based on the logs you provides, it seems like there was an error during code compilation and pack.

Ionic hides the error detail when you run **ionic serve**. You can get detail error information by running this command **npm run build --verbose**.

If you see the error is something like **Cannot read property 'substr'**, you can try to move every class into a single .ts file.

Answer (score 0):

npm run build --verbose :

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'run',
npm verb cli   'build',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@5.3.0
npm info using node@v6.11.1
npm verb run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
npm info lifecycle gecina-plan-prevention@0.0.1~prebuild: gecina-plan-prevention@0.0.1
npm info lifecycle gecina-plan-prevention@0.0.1~build: gecina-plan-prevention@0.0.1

> gecina-plan-prevention@0.0.1 build /srv/pvx/mobile/gecina
> ionic-app-scripts build

[08:40:35]  ionic-app-scripts 1.3.4 
[08:40:35]  build dev started ... 
[08:40:35]  clean started ... 
[08:40:35]  clean finished in 1 ms 
[08:40:35]  copy started ... 
[08:40:35]  transpile started ... 
[08:40:37]  transpile finished in 2.37 s 
[08:40:37]  preprocess started ... 
[08:40:37]  deeplinks started ... 
[08:40:37]  deeplinks finished in 88 ms 
[08:40:37]  preprocess finished in 88 ms 
[08:40:37]  webpack started ... 
[08:40:37]  copy finished in 2.57 s 
/srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:115
        node.add(nextLine.substr(0, mapping.generatedColumn));
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
    at Function.<anonymous> (/srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:115:26)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (/srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:155:14)
    at Function.SourceNode_fromStringWithSourceMap [as fromStringWithSourceMap] (/srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:80:24)
    at SourceMapSource.node (/srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/SourceMapSource.js:42:20)
    at ReplaceSource.node (/srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/ReplaceSource.js:69:29)
    at CachedSource.node (/srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/CachedSource.js:12:23)
    at /srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/ConcatSource.js:40:49
    at Array.map (native)
    at ConcatSource.node (/srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/ConcatSource.js:39:60)
npm verb lifecycle gecina-plan-prevention@0.0.1~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle gecina-plan-prevention@0.0.1~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/pgsql/bin/:/usr/local/pgsql/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
npm verb lifecycle gecina-plan-prevention@0.0.1~build: CWD: /srv/pvx/mobile/gecina
npm info lifecycle gecina-plan-prevention@0.0.1~build: Failed to exec build script
npm verb stack Error: gecina-plan-prevention@0.0.1 build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm verb stack Exit status 1
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:289:16)
npm verb stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
npm verb stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
npm verb pkgid gecina-plan-prevention@0.0.1
npm verb cwd /srv/pvx/mobile/gecina
npm verb Linux 4.4.0-83-generic
npm verb argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build" "--verbose"
npm verb node v6.11.1
npm verb npm  v5.3.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gecina-plan-prevention@0.0.1 build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the gecina-plan-prevention@0.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ldt/.npm/_logs/2017-08-01T06_40_44_582Z-debug.log
```

ionic info :

```
cli packages:

    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.5.0 (/srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova)
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.0 (/srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular)
    @ionic/cli-utils                : 1.6.0 (/srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils)
    ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.6.0 (/srv/pvx/mobile/gecina/node_modules/ionic)

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.1.1

System:

    Node : v6.11.1
    OS   : Linux 4.4
    npm  : 5.3.0
```

ionic serve -l -s -c :

```
[INFO] Starting app-scripts server: --consolelogs --c --serverlogs --s --lab --l --port 8100 --p 8100 --livereload-port
       35729 --r 35729 --address 0.0.0.0 - Ctrl+C to cancel
[08:46:04]  watch started ... 
[08:46:04]  build dev started ... 
[08:46:04]  Proxy added:/api => http://[...] 
[08:46:04]  clean started ... 
[08:46:04]  clean finished in 1 ms 
[08:46:04]  copy started ... 
[08:46:04]  transpile started ... 
[08:46:06]  transpile finished in 2.24 s 
[08:46:06]  preprocess started ... 
[08:46:06]  deeplinks started ... 
[08:46:06]  deeplinks finished in 81 ms 
[08:46:06]  preprocess finished in 81 ms 
[08:46:06]  webpack started ... 
[08:46:06]  copy finished in 2.43 s
```